# Kohana на виртуалке Ubuntu Linux. Долго загружаются страницы

Tags: ubuntu, kohana, virtualbox

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой. 
Разрабатывал проект на фреймворке KOHANA используя Denwer.

Пришла необходимость перенести его на ОС Linux. 
Я установил VirtualBox и создал машину Ubuntu Linux на которой создал сервер. 
Создал общие папки, сеть и в результате сайт доступен на хостовой машине по моему IP.

Но появилась проблема. Страницы движка Коханы грузятся примерно 3-6 секунд. Даже пусть то будет обычный файлик "Hello World".
Проверял работу сервера без фреймворка и движка - все летает. PhpMyAdmin - летает. 
А вот сайт дуплит долго. Скачал и поставил новенькую голую кохану - все равно.

Странно то, что на Денвере все было идеально и быстро. Тут же начались сильные задержки.. Помогите пожалуйста. Возможно есть предположения, из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: посмотрите логи апача. Может там что то интересное и появится. Иногда так бывает, что в лог пишется так много, что в результате все это тормозит.

Comment: присоединяюсь к вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Если используете гуевую убунту, то вопрос отпадает сам по себе. ставьте ubuntu server и посвежее (14.04-10). Ну и понятно что на виртуалке скорость будет несколько ниже чем на родительской машине. Во-первых - ресурсов меньше (можно попробовать выделить больше), во-вторых - много зависит от файловой системы (с этим тоже можно поиграться).

и для таких вещей придумали vagrant, конфиг легко и быстро можно слепить  [тут](https://puphpet.com/)

Comment: "Если используете гуевую убунту, то вопрос отпадает сам по себе." - с чего бы?

Comment: из личного опыта, гуевая убунта даже при выделении большего количества ресурсов в приведенном кейсе работает медленней чем серверная

Comment: В программировании нет понятия "личный опыт". Сам по себе графический интерфейс не ест все доступные ресурсы и не пишет ничего на диск в постоянном режиме (первое, что вызывает "ощутимые глазу" задержки).